# CSS animation cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser

I created a CSS animated logo with all the animation code inside the same SVG file so that it could be uploaded or referenced and the animation would play without any additional effort. It seems to be working fine except on microsoft browsers and iPhones(tested on safari and chrome). On internet explorer the animation fails to play almost entirely. In iOS platforms the animation plays but it seems some instructions are ignored or misinterpreted. Specifically:

• The scale instruction supposed to create the blinking eyes seems to be set to a different origin making the eyes move instead of scaling in place.

• The ear flaps aren't "rotating". Actually they are rotating, but they are suposed to move along with the rest of the elements and instead they just rotate in place. It seems the translate instructions are being ignored.

Here is a link to the file.

https://clevergap.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/pet-friendly-logo-anim-01-3.svg

Here's the CSS for the areas that aren't displaying correctly in iOS.

```
@keyframes eyes-anim {
  0% {transform: scale(1, 0) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
  24% {transform: scale(1, 0) translate(0, -22.5%); transform-origin: 50% 27.5%;}
  26% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0%); transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
  28% {transform: scale(1, 0) translate(0, -22.5%); transform-origin: 50% 27.5%;}
  30% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0%); transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
  65% {transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 35%;}
  67% {transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(15deg); transform-origin: 50% 35%;}
  90% {transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(15deg); transform-origin: 50% 35%;}
  93% {transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 35%;}
  100% {transform: scale(1, 1) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 35%;}
}

@keyframes earlobe-right-anim {
  0% {transform: scale(0, 0) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  43% {transform: scale(0, 0) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  45% {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  49% {transform: scale(.95, .95) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  53% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  65% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  67% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, 4.4%) rotateZ(-25deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  70% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, 4.4%) rotateZ(25deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  72% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, 4.4%) rotateZ(17deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  76% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, 4.4%) rotateZ(20deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  90% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, 4.4%) rotateZ(20deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  94% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(-10deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  97% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(5deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}
  100% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 65% 11.25%;}  
}

@keyframes earlobe-left-anim {
  0% {transform: scale(0, 0) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  43% {transform: scale(0, 0) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  45% {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  49% {transform: scale(.95, .95) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  53% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  65% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  67% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, -3%) rotateZ(25deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  72% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, -3%) rotateZ(-25deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  75% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, -3%) rotateZ(-17deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  77% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, -3%) rotateZ(-20deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  90% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(6%, -3%) rotateZ(-20deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  93% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(10deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  96% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(-5deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}
  100% {transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0) rotateZ(0deg); transform-origin: 35% 11.25%;}  
}

#Earlobe-Left path {
    animation-name: earlobe-left-anim;
    animation-duration: 7000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
#Earlobe-Right path {
    animation-name: earlobe-right-anim;
    animation-duration: 7000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#Eyes circle, #Eyes ellipse, #Eyes path {
    animation-name: eyes-anim;
    animation-duration: 7000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Internet explorer [does not support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) CSS transform for SVG elements. For Webkit/iOS, try to explicitely set `transform-box`.

Comment: I tried setting transform-box, still fails to apply some of the transformations on iOS.